# Word to describe quality being fit to each other

Tags: word-choice

[image]

Is there any good noun to describe the quality being fit to each other? The picture as example, either of the two halves fits to the other. At this point, I want to make a sentence like this: Either of the two has [quality] [proper prep.] the other.

Thanks.

Comment: is a *good fit* for the other,  is a *good match* for the other, were *made for* each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two are perfectly [compatible](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=compatibility&submit.x=0&submit.y=0).

> adj
>
> 1. Capable of existing or performing in harmonious, agreeable, or congenial combination with another or others: *compatible family relationships*.

The noun is *compatibility*, so you can say *They have compatibility*, but using the adjective as above is a simpler and stronger style.

Your template sentence uses *Either.* One of the definitions of *either* is *both*, however we don't normally use *either* in the way that you do. Some will say it's incorrect or unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Complementary: serving to fill out or complete
Reference : Merriam Webster online dictionary